# Android ADB Shell Commands -Xms & -Xmx not working

Tags: android, performance, shell, adb, dalvik

How can we set dalvikvm parameters -Xms & -Xmx through adb shell or any other method for a specific android application?
This is needed to avoid the lag in my application while GC

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in your IDE, example for eclipse in Run Configuration> Vm Arguments

you enter

`-Xmx800m -Xms500m`

Comment: there is no **Vm Arguments** in Run Configuration for Android Application

Comment: I tried using **adb shell dalvikvm -Xms128m** got a response as **Dalvik VM init failed (check log file)**

Comment: @alban you said for spesific android application?

Comment: yes I want to allocate 128MB of initial memory to my application, right now its allocating only 5-6 MB of memory resulting in very frequent GC

Comment: Okay i understand, Maybe it be related to root authority?

Comment: the device is rooted and su permission is there